# send data from IntentService to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-bundle

As i tried BroadCastReciever in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213949/broadcastreciver-passed-to-sharedpreference-value-not-updated-programticly), I'v tried pass data with **arguments** too  in my Log it's ok .

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
ArticleDetailFragment fragobj = new ArticleDetailFragment().newInstance2(jsonString);
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: " + bundle);
```

but i received null :

```
public static ArticleDetailFragment newInstance2(String item) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("edttext", item);
        ArticleDetailFragment fragment = new ArticleDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }
```

in my onCreateView() :

```
Log.i(TAG, "onCreateViewBundle: " + getArguments().getString("edttext"));
```

what is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

this is because you first set the correct fragment arguments with the correct data and then you override it outside the newInstance2.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
ArticleDetailFragment fragobj = new ArticleDetailFragment().newInstance2(jsonString);
fragobj.setArguments(bundle); // <- here you override the arguments that were set inside newInstance with a bundle that has no data in it
Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: " + bundle);
```

should be

```
ArticleDetailFragment fragobj = ArticleDetailFragment().newInstance2(jsonString);
Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: " + fragobj.getArguments().getString("edttext"));
```

Also the other answer says to remove `new` keyword. He is right!

Comment: the same issue .

Comment: then jsonString is actually null when you create the fragment. I would recommend passing some random string, just to see that it works as expected and if it works, investigate why jsonString comes null

Comment: my code was like `bundle.putString("edttext", jsonString);
                            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);` 
so when i logged bundel i get the data as i remind above, and yes i tried what you said, returned null.